# PHP: Repair Mongodb using MongoDB\Driver

Tags: php, mongodb

I need to rewrite this codes to using MongoDB\Driver.

But I cant find how to repair database.

Please anyone give me a example to repair MongoDB database with MongoDB\Driver.

Thank you.

**codes using MongoClinent:**

```php
$mongo = new MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017');
$db = $mongo->selectDB('databaseName');
$collection = $db->selectCollection('collectionName');
$date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-1 month"));
$result = $collection->remove(array('date' => array( '$lt' => $date)));
if(0 < $result["n"]){
    $db->repair();
}
```

**code using MongoDB\Driver:**

```php
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://localhost:27017');
$date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-1 month"));
$bulk->delete(['date' => ['$lt' => $date], ['limit' => false]]);
$result = $manager->executeBulkWrite('databaseName.collectionName', $bulk);
if(0 < $result["n"]){
    // *** I don't know how to write ***
}
```

Comment: Are you sure repair is what you want to run?  The repairDatabase command was [removed in the current version of MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.2-compatibility/#remove-support-for-the-repairdatabase-command)

Comment: I use MongoDB version 3.6.3. Your comment tell me that I should reconsider how implement this. I had assumed I need to rewrite this as same as the original code. Thank you.